# Confused by Use of ~ in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I am programming for the first time in ASP.NET.  It's proven to be very easy and I'm really enjoying it.  One feature I like is that, within a web page, I can reference files from root by using the tilde (~) character and then the rest of the path.  However, this does not seem to be consistent.  For example, it works within the context of href, e.g.

```
<link href="~/css/StyleSheet.css" />
```

It doesn't work with respect to src, e.g.

```
<img src="~/images/header.jpg" />
```

Why is this?  Is there something I'm doing wrong.  The inconsistency is annoying.

Comment: The ~ operator will work for both HTML and server controls if you also include the runat="server" attribute as well. In this sense, the accepted answer below is not entirely correct.

Comment: @IrishChieftain - in what sense is an HTML control with runat="server" not a server control?!

Comment: I was trying to say that adding the runat="server" to a HTML control (thus making it a server control) WITHOUT the "~" operator, may not work. I'll stand corrected if I'm wrong :-)

Comment: Ah, I see - I thought you were trying to make a distinction between different types of controls that had runat="server", not whether they were using the `~`. I gotcha now :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From my experience the `~` trick only works in server controls. If your img has `runat="server"` that should fix it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Is it really a good idea having everything runat server, though?  To me that seems like it would burden the server.  (In either case, answer marked as accepted.)

Comment: yese, use the server tags with caution,and where ever you can use html tags (without runat=server) go for it. And if you are using html/server controls in user controls, dont include your stylesheets in the usercontrol, include them in the parent page which will consume the user control

Comment: @Jason: No, it's not a good idea to have *everything* runat=server. ASP.Net does handle large number of controls, but the less it has to parse, the better.

Also, server controls can add markup or change markup, and while you have control over changing it with .browser files and the like, you get much more control with raw HTML.

Answer (score 3):

[ASP.NET Web Site Paths](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178116.aspx)

> To overcome these disadvantages,
>   ASP.NET includes the Web application
>   root operator (~), which you can use
>   when specifying a path in server
>   controls. ASP.NET resolves the ~
>   operator to the root of the current
>   application. You can use the ~
>   operator in conjunction with folders
>   to specify a path that is based on the
>   current root.

...

> You can use the ~ operator in any
>   path-related property in server
>   controls. The ~ operator is recognized
>   only for server controls and in server
>   code. You cannot use the ~ operator
>   for client elements.